# Race conditions in AR destroy callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, race-condition

I seem to have a race condition in my Rails app. While deleting a user and all of the associated models that depend on it, new associated models are sometimes created by the user. User deletions can take a while if we're deleting a lot of content, so it makes sense that race conditions would exist here. This ends up creating models that point to a user that doesn't exist.

I've tried fixing this by creating a UserDeletion model, which acts as a sort of mutex lock. Before it starts deleting the user, it'll create a new UserDeletion record. When a user tries to create new content, it checks to make sure an associated UserDeletion record doesn't exist. After it's done, it deletes it.

This hasn't solved the problem, though, so I'm wondering how other people have handled similar issues with AR callbacks and race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

First of all when there is a lot of content associated, we moved on to use manual delete process using SQL `DELETE` instead off Rails `destroy`. (Though this may not work for You, If You carelessly introduced a lot of callback dependencies that does something after record is destroyed)

```
def custom_delete
  self.class.transaction do
    related_objects.delete_all
    related_objects_2.delete_all
    delete
  end
end
```

If You find Yourself writing this all the time, You can simply wrap it inside class method that accepts list of related_objects keys to delete.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def bulk_delete_related(*args)
      define_method "custom_delete" do
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          args.each do |field|
            send(field).delete_all
          end
        end

        delete
      end
    end
  end
end


class SomeModel < ActiverRecord::Base
  bulk_delete :related_objects, :related_objects2, :related_object
end
```

I inserted the class method inside ActiveRecord::Base class directly, but probably You should better extract it to module. Also this only speeds things up, but does not resolve the original problem.

Secondly You can introduce FK constraints (we did that to ensure integrity, as we do a lot of custom SQL). It will work the way that User won't be deleted as long as there are linked objects. Though it might not be what You want. To increase effectivity of this solution You can always delegate user deletion to a background job, that will retry deleting user until it's actually can be deleted (no new objects dropped in)

Alternatively You can do the other way around as we did at my previous work in some cases. If it's more important to delete user rather than to be sure that there are no zombie records, use some swipe process to clean up time to time.

Finally the truth is somewhere in the middle - apply constraints to relations that definitely need to be cleaned up before removing user and just rely on sweeper to remove less important ones that shouldn't interfere with user deletion.

Problem is not trivial but it should be solvable to some extent.